# IntelliJ IDEA code completion popup does not appear on Ctrl+Space after entering few arguments of method

Tags: intellij-idea

Suppose I have a method:

```
addUser(String userid, String email, String phoneNo){..}
```

When I write only two arguments `addUser("martin","asd@gmail.com"` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> then IntelliJ IDEA does not show the arguments that are accepted by this method.

Instead I need to remove them and type `api.` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code completion is supposed to work differently, once you choose `addUser` from the popup, you will have something like this:

[image: completion]

Type the parameter values and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to switch to the next one.

Parameter info can be shown automatically:

[image: parameter info]

or manually on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (`View` | `Show Parameter Info`):

[image: parameter info]

Code completion popup will appear after typing `,` next to the second parameter and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Comment: Do you know any more setting that speed up intelliJ coding then please share link.

Comment: See https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2015/10/intellij-idea-tips-and-tricks/